# PHP error while connecting to database

Tags: php, database, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a database that I created using this code:

```
<?php
function Conectarse()
{
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="root";
    $bda="toobebe_catalogo";

    if (!($link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)))
    {
        echo "Error conectando a la base de datos.<br>";
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Éxito conectando con la base de datos.<br>";
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db($bda,$link))
    {
        echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos.<br>";
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Éxito al encontrar la base de datos.<br>";
    }
    return $link;
}

$conn=Conectarse();

$sql="SELECT * FROM toobebe-octubre";
$db_fila = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$ok=1;

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_fila)) && $ok) 
{
    $valor=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$valor)
{
    $ok=0;
}   
}
```

?>

But it fires this mistake when I execute it:

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
```

I've been searching, and to know:
- Database exists

- Permissions are correct
- Table exists
- Table is not null

Any idea on why this mistake is happening?

**EDIT:**
Added image with the mistake:
[image: Image error]

Comment: The full error line would be helpful. Did you ever try to insert the value of `$sql` directly into your database via PHPMyAdmin or something similiar? From the Docs: `mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error`. `FALSE` = boolean

Comment: use PDO please  instead of this

Comment: mysql_connect will be depricated soon so better use PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't with connecting to the Database, but rather with your query. You have a hyphen in your table name, so you should try and enclose it as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `toobebe-octubre`";
$db_fila = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$ok = 1;

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_fila)) && $ok) 
{
    $valor=mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if(!$valor)
    {
       $ok=0;
    }   
}
```

Just a couple of tips, using `mysql_*` is severely deprecated now. You should really be using `mysqli_*` at a very minimum, or PDO.

Also, `SELECT *` is generally considered a bad practice, because I really doubt you do need *everything* from the table.

Comment: I do really need to select all from my database, as I created it with articles and I need to select all of them to insert hem into a new and more complicated table. Do you mean with 'toobebe-octubre' with simple quotes? Because it doesn't look like that and it doesn't work at all...

Comment: No, they're not single quotes, but rather backticks.

Comment: Sorry, couln't at first 10 minutes and I forgot until now... You were so fast ;)